# Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException:

Tags: runtimeexception

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.poster, PID: 23677
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.poster/com.example.poster.MainActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your getInstance() call.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your getInstance() call.
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:114)
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:71)
at com.example.poster.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)

Answer (score 0):

1. add these dipendencies for java

   ```
      implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
   ```
2. for kotlin

   ```
      implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2') 
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
   ```
3. then if using instance outside us1 for the database add url

   ```
      FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("**url here**);
      DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("**path here**");
   ```